# Django object memory usage

Tags: python, django

Coming from a Java environment I've been quite surprised how simple Python/Django generally is and how it handles objects in memory. One thing that I've never found a clear answer about is what would be the best practice to instantiate objects to ensure when requests are made through Django each request refers to the same object.

An example of this would be within my views.py file I may reference to a UserService() class. What's the best practice to instantiate this class?

Is it safe to do it within the def/class view itself?

```
def test_view(request, format=None):
    service = UserService()
    service.to_something()
    return Response( status=status.HTTP_200_OK )
```

Or should it be done at the top of the views.py file then references within the def/class view?

```
service = UserService()

def test_view(request, format=None):        
    service.to_something()
    return Response( status=status.HTTP_200_OK )
```

Or should it be instantiated elsewhere?

The goal is to ensure the least amount of objects are created and referred to. I understand that python holds a reference count against each object as it's created, but am unclear on how that may place into this.

Additionally when creating a objects, let's say a service. How necessary is it to instantiate the classes you wish to use throughout the service within the **init** method first? Given the efficiency of the python GC it something I've wondered when it comes towards best practices and being as pythonic as possible.

Comment: You'll need to be a bit more specific about what UserService is. Usually in Python we don't bother about services or factories, we just call functions. Is this service keeping state? If not, it probably shouldn't be a class at all. If so, do you want that state preserved across requests?

Comment: UserService is a class from my own library that contains some of my core business logic. I'm so use to creating classes that I don't think much about not needing them :).

To help answer your question about keeping state. What I'm attempting to do is figure out if I need to approach object instantiation via IoC or DI so that I don't rebuild classes over and over. So yes, I'd like to reserve the state across requests.

Comment: My main concern is the memory bloat. Is it safe to assume that if I don't use classes and simply use functions within my UserService.py file then that would be considered more pythonic as well as mitigate memory bloat when referring to the py file within different locations in my codebase? Sorry for the extended questioning. I've been trying to gain a grasp towards how classes/py files should be implemented to ensure the best level of memory efficiency within my applications.

Comment: Memory isn't really an issue here, particularly if there's no data associated with the class instance. But in any case, the class instantiated inside the function will go out of scope when the function ends and the memory reclaimed then; whereas a class instantiated at module level will remain as long as the process does (the webserver determines how long the process lasts). The Pythonic thing to do is to have all the user functions in a module, and import that as necessary.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback Daniel.

Comment: I've started a new thread to ask a more general question that I think will help find the answers I'm looking for.

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31642325/need-some-clarity-on-how-to-best-reuse-objects-using-django