# Pythonic Django object reuse

Tags: python, django

I've been racking my brain on this for the last few weeks and I just can't seem to understand it. I'm hoping you folks here can give me some clarity.

**A LITTLE BACKGROUND**
I've built an API to help serve a large website and like all of us, are trying to keep the API as efficient as possible. Part of this efficiency is to NOT create an object that contains custom business logic over and over again (Example: a service class) as requests are made. To give some personal background I come from the Java world so I'm use to using a IoC or DI to help handle object creation and injection into my classes to ensure classes are NOT created over and over on a per request basis.

**WHAT I'VE READ**
While looking at many Python IoC and DI posts I've become rather confused on how to best approach creating a given class and not having to worry about the server getting overloaded with too many objects based on the amount of requests it may be handling.

Some people say an IoC or DI really isn't needed. But as I run my Django app I find that unless I construct the object I want globally (top of file) for views.py to use later rather than within each view class or def within views.py I run the change of creating multiple classes of the same type, which from what I understand would cause memory bloat on the server.

So what's the right way to be pythonic to keep objects from being built over and over? Should I invest in using an IoC / DI or not? Can I safely rely on setting up my service.py files to just contain def's instead of classes that contain def's? Is the garbage collector just THAT efficient so I don't even have to worry about it.

I've purposely not placed any code in this post since this seems like a general questions, but I can provide a few code examples if that helps.

Thanks
From a confused engineer that wants to be as pythonic as possible

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You come from a background where everything *needs* to be a class, I've programmed web apps in Java too, and sometimes it's harder to unlearn old things than to learn new things, I understand.

In Python / Django you wouldn't make anything a class unless you need many instances and need to keep state.

For a service that's hardly the case, and sometimes you'll notice in Java-like web apps some services are made singletons, which is just a workaround and a rather big anti-pattern in Python

### Pythonic

Python is flexible enough so that a "services class" isn't required, you'd just have a Python module (e.g. `services.py`) with a number of *functions*, emphasis on being a function that takes in something, returns something, in a completely stateless fashion.

```
# services.py
# this is a module, doesn't keep any state within,
# it may read and write to the DB, do some processing etc but doesn't remember things
def get_scores(student_id):
    return Score.objects.filter(student=student_id)

# views.py
# receives HTTP requests 
def view_scores(request, student_id):
    scores = services.get_scores(student_id)
    # e.g. use the scores queryset in a template return HTML page
```

Notice how if you need to swap out the service, you'll just be swapping out a single Python module (just a file really), so Pythonistas hardly bother with *explicit* interfaces and other abstractions.

### Memory

Now per each "django worker process", you'd have that one `services` module, that is used over and over for all requests that come in, and when the `Score` queryset is used and no longer pointed at in memory, it'll be cleaned up.

I saw your other post, and well, instantiating a `ScoreService` object for each request, or keeping an instance of it in the global scope is just unnecessary, the above example does the job with one module in memory, and doesn't need us to be smart about it.

And if you *did* need to keep state in-between several requests, keeping them in online instances of `ScoreService` would be a bad idea anyway because now every user might need one instance, that's not viable (too many online objects keeping context). Not to mention that instance is only accessible from the same process unless you have some sharing mechanisms in place.

### Keep state in a datastore

In case you want to keep state in-between requests, you'd keep the state in a datastore, and when the request comes in, you hit the `services` module again to get the context back from the datastore, pick up where you left it and do your business, return your HTTP response, then unused things will get garbage collected.

The emphasis being on keeping things stateless, where any given HTTP request can be processed on any given django process, and all state objects are garbage collected after the response is returned and objects go out of scope.

This may not be the fastest request/response cycle we can pull, but it's scalable as hell

### Look at some major web apps written in Django

I suggest you look at some open source Django projects and look at how they're organized, you'll see a lot of the things you're busting your brains with, Djangonauts just don't bother with.

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for. Great explanation.